# Office365 API OutlookServicesClient hangs when acquiring token

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, office365, office365-apps

I am following the example from here: [Get started with Office 365 APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/getting-started-Office-365-APIs)

When my controller action executes, it hangs on the following line inside of var "new OutlookServicesClient"

```
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
    dcr.ServiceResourceId,
    new ClientCredential(this.configuration.IdaClientID, this.configuration.IdaClientSecret),
    new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

I cannot figure out why it is hanging, especially, since AcquireTokenSilentAsync works just fine in the discovery client right before this call.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Controller Action Method:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{    
    var contacts = new List<ContactItem>();
    var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypesAdditions.ObjectIdentifier).Value;

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(this.configuration.IdaAuthority, new AdalTokenCache(signInUserId));

    try
    {
        var discClient = new DiscoveryClient(
            new Uri(this.configuration.Office365DiscoveryServiceEndpoint),
            async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
                    this.configuration.Office365DiscoveryResourceID,
                    new ClientCredential(this.configuration.IdaClientID, this.configuration.IdaClientSecret),
                    new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            });

        var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync("Contacts");

        var exClient = new OutlookServicesClient(
            dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
            async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
                    dcr.ServiceResourceId,
                    new ClientCredential(this.configuration.IdaClientID, this.configuration.IdaClientSecret),
                    new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            });

        var contactsResult = await exClient.Me.Contacts.ExecuteAsync();

        do
        {
            var c = contactsResult.CurrentPage;
            contacts.AddRange(c.Select(contact => new ContactItem { FirstName = contact.GivenName }));

            contactsResult = await contactsResult.GetNextPageAsync();
        }
        while (contactsResult != null);
    }
    catch (AdalException exception)
    {
        if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
        {
            authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
        }
    }

    return this.View("Index", contacts);
}
```

Comment: I'd try using Fiddler or some other network tracing tool to see if a request is just never coming back.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything coming back.  I placed breakpoints in each of the 2 async function and can see the authresult returned in the first, but nothing happens in the 2nd.

Comment: Do you see a POST to login.microsoftonline.com?

Comment: I do not see any calls going out for either DiscoveryClient or OutlookServicesClient when the calls should be happening.  This may be a fiddler setup issue though.  As I am requesting the Index method on my controller, fiddler shows it as downloading the whole time all of the inner workings are happening.  So it doesn't pick up any of the inner async calls.  I know the first one is happening, because if I debug, I can break inside the async func and see the access token getting returned for the discovery client.
So, it is listening to my async controller action, but not the async MSFT calls.

Comment: The calls don't happen until they are needed. So for the OutlookServicesClient, you wouldn't see the AcquireTokenSilentAsync until the exClient.Me.Contacts.ExecuteAsync happens. Basically the client defers getting a token until it actually needs it.

Comment: Right.  And when I break on that call, I also have a break on "var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync" inside the async func of "new OutlookServicesClient".  I get to the point where the request for the token is made.  The call is made and then it just hangs and never returns anything.  I never get to my return statement in the async func. (That is where I said I don't see anything coming through fiddler.)

Comment: Any more info regarding this? I'm having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in version of 1.0.34 Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Portable that causes a deadlock in OutlookServiceClient. Reverting to 1.0.22 seems to work.

This is documented here https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start/commit/b5652864756636a0b141c222e964aba953357e7a#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R139

And looks to be fixed in the next release as seen here
https://github.com/Microsoft/Vipr/commit/aaeff5cb94204c23d7501be8fa74b0260ddc52d9

Comment: You can do Stefan's fix, or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792928/why-does-the-office-365-outlookservices-v1-0-34-net-client-library-hang-indef